# Simple Injector 3 does not return general instances

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am using Simple Injector and just updated from v2 to v3.
I am using the DI container to resolve associated event handlers to an event.

All EventHandlers implement the interface `IDomainEventHandler` and all events implement `IDomainEvent`.

The EventHandlers are registered:

```
container.Register(typeof(IDomainEventHandler<>),
    new[] { typeof(IDomainEventHandler).Assembly });
```

I collect all handlers to a certain event like so:

```
public void Dispatch<TDomainEvent>(TDomainEvent domainEvent) 
    where TDomainEvent : IDomainEvent
{
    var eventHandlers =
        _dependencyResolver.GetAllInstances<IDomainEventHandler<TDomainEvent>>();

    foreach (var domainEventHandler in eventHandlers)
        domainEventHandler.Handle(domainEvent); 
}
```

I have a general event handler, which handles all events who implements `IDomainEvent` interface. It is defined like this:

```
public class EventStoreDomainEventHandler : IDomainEventHandler<IDomainEvent>
{
    public void Handle(IDomainEvent domainEvent)
    { ... }
}
```

When I try to get all instances from the DI container of a certain event which implements the `IDomainEvent` interface, I don't receive an instance of the `EventStoreDomainEventhandler`.

Is there a way to register and get all handlers of a type, and also all handlers associated to interfaces implemented by the type?

Hope it makes sense :o)

Kind Regards
Frederik

Comment: I assume your real registration is using `RegisterCollection`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because Simple Injector [separates registration of collections from one-to-one mappings](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/decisions.html#separate-collections), while you are registering your handlers with `Register`, while you are resolving them with `GetAllInstances`. You should either use the following combination:

```
container.Register(typeof(IDomainEventHandler<>), assemblies);

_dependencyResolver.GetInstance<IDomainEventHandler<TDomainEvent>>();
```

or:

```
// NOTE: v4.3+ syntax
container.Collection.Register(typeof(IDomainEventHandler<>), assemblies);

_dependencyResolver.GetAllInstances<IDomainEventHandler<TDomainEvent>>();
```

Comment: This issue pops up all the time. Is there a diagnostic warning that can be defined that helps in detecting this kind of faulty registrations?

Comment: @Maarten: That's an interesting point. I think the real issue here is that Simple Injector will resolve collections for you even if you haven't registered them. I consider this a design flaw, but that is something that I considered this to be a too large breaking change. We'll have to wait for v4 :'(. I'm not sure that diagnostics would help, because users will usually spot this error before they look in the diagnostic messages.

Comment: @Maarten I'm happy to say [this](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/98) has been resolved sooner than v4 :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly state the variance ***in*** within your interface definition

```
public interface IDomainEventHandler<in TDomainEvent> { }
```

> marking the interface with in and out keywords communicates that covariance and contravariance is expected and there could therefore be multiple applicable implementations

See [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#covariance-contravariance) for full details.